# Reflexive Pronouns and Relative Clauses

Tags: syntax, english, pronouns, binding-theory, reflexive

At least in my dialect of English, sentences like the following are perfectly grammatical:

> The picture of himself<sub>i</sub> that Tom<sub>i</sub> most liked is on the table.

How does one account for the binding here? If you accept Principle A, then at some point in the derivation of this sentence, *Tom* is going to have to c-command *the picture of himself*. That doesn’t work with at least one traditional way of deriving relative clauses (where a possibly silent relative operator is merged into [Spec, CP] of the relative clause, and then the whole thing merges as an adjunct to the nominal *picture of himself*). I can imagine raising analyses that handle the problem, but those may run into other issues.

Is there a standard way of dealing with this?

Comment: One point: the relative clause doesn't "merge as a complement to the NP picture of himself", but as modifier. "Picture of himself" is not an NP, but a nominal.

Comment: Oops, thank you. I changed “complement” to “adjunct” and “NP” to “nominal.” I hope that’s better.